# Group multiplications in $Spin(d)$ via $(a,q) \in (\mathbb{Z}/2, SO(d))$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, group-extensions

We know that the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\to Spin(d) \to SO(d) \to 1$.

Given the groups $A$ and $Q$, we require to have the additional data
the 2-cocycle $ f \in H^2(BQ,A)$ and the map $r: Q \to Aut(A)$:
$$
A, \quad Q, \quad f \in H^2(BQ,A),\quad r: Q \to Aut(A)
$$
to
specify the group extension $0 \to A\to E \to Q \to 1$,

$BQ$ is the classifying space of $Q$. The $A$ is the normal subgroup of $E$.

For
$$
A=\mathbb{Z}/2, \quad Q=SO(d), \quad f =
w_2(V_{SO(d)}) \in  H^2(BSO(d),\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2,\quad r: SO(d)\to Aut(\mathbb{Z}/2)=0
$$
here $w_2(V_{SO(d)})$ is a nontrivial 2-cocycle

Below is my attempt to determine the group multiplications in $g \in Spin(d)$ via $(a,q) \in (\mathbb{Z}/2, SO(d))$.

So given $g_1, g_2 \in  Spin(d)$, we can write both as a doublet:

$$g_1=(a_1,q_1),\quad g_2=(a_2,q_2)\in (\mathbb{Z}/2,SO(d)), $$

> Question: How could we reproduce the group multiplication rule of $g_1 \cdot g_2 \in  Spin(d)$ via $(a_1,q_1)\cdot (a_2,q_2)$ in terms of the above data $A,Q,f,r$:

> $$g_1 \cdot g_2 =(a_1,q_1)\cdot (a_2,q_2)
> =(a_1+r(q_2) a_2+f(q_1,q_2),q_1 q_2)$$

since $r$ is trivial identity map,

> $$=(a_1,q_1)\cdot (a_2,q_2)
> =(a_1+ a_2+f(q_1,q_2),q_1 q_2)=?$$
> how can we write the $f =
> w_2(V_{SO(d)}) \in  H^2(BSO(d),\mathbb{Z}/2)$ of the second Stiefel Whitney class in terms of the $f(q_1,q_2)$ give the data of $q_1,q_2 \in SO(d)$? fully determine the multiplication rules?

> $f(q_1,q_2)=?$

Comment: @peter thanks for comment, I thought about d=2,3